# Pandas hash_pandas_object checksum values not staying stable

Tags: pandas

I have some code that is using pandas to prep a few sets of values for insert into a DB and it's creating a checksum to determine if today's value is different than yesterdays value. This is working great for most of the data pulls but for one of them it is flipping between two values on alternate days therefore inserting duplicate rows into the database.

```
flat_df['checksum_digits'] = hash_pandas_object(flat_df, index=False).apply(str)
```

What I have checked:

- I don't have any columns that are compound objects. Every column is a string or numeric value.
- This is only happening on live. I can't reproduce it on my dev machine.

Versions:

- Python 3.5.2
- Pandas 0.24.2

What else can I check to troubleshoot the checksum generation?